Reverse proxy in ASP.NET Core: how to return the HTTP status code from destination server?
I'm using ASP.NET Core and Flurl to write a reverse proxy that sends requests to one destination server, another server, or both, depending on how the reverse proxy is configured at runtime.  I want the proxy's responses to match the responses from the other servers as much as possible, including HTTP status codes.  If I simplify it a lot, my code looks like this:
app.MapGet("test", async (string input) =>
{
    // For simplicity, we'll use only one destination server in this example.
    string serviceUrl = "https://my.server.here/api";
    return await serviceUrl.AppendPathSegment(input).GetJsonAsync<MyOutputClass>();
})
.WithName("Test")
.WithOpenApi();

If the destination server returns a JSON object of the expected type and a 200 status code, then great -- so does my proxy.  But if the destination server returns, say, a 400 status code with a message, then my proxy wraps that information in a different type of object and returns a 500 status code.  I don't want that; I want the proxy to return 400 in that case.  What's a good way for the code to say "call this and whatever response you get, return that as our response, too"?  I can drop Flurl if that helps, but I'd prefer to keep using ASP.NET Core.  And, of course, I'd like not to have to check for every possible status code that the destination server could return.

Flurl go to exception when call failed. You could try return a custom response.
app.MapGet("test", async (string input,HttpContext httpContext) =>
{
    try
    {
        string serviceUrl = "https://localhost:7224/";
        return await serviceUrl.AppendPathSegment(input).GetJsonAsync<object>();
    }
    catch (FlurlHttpException ex)
    {
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = ex.Call.Response.StatusCode;
        return ex.Message;
    }
})
.WithName("Test");
.WithOpenApi();


Thank you for the suggestion.  The StatusCode part works, but for the body, I get "Call failed with status code 400 (Bad Request): POST https://app-[url]".  The body of the original response message is lost.
